# Undefined control sequence.\end{frame}

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeWarsaw}
\renewcommand\textbullet{\ensuremath{\bullet}}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%\usecolortheme{seagull}

\title[monExemple]{Un exemple sur le Beamer}
\subtitle{created with beamer 3.x}
\author[bela]{A.belahcene}
\institute{ IAP, Boumerdes}


\setbeamertemplate{itemise item }[ball]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=blue!50}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=white,bg=red}


\begin{document}    





\subsection{Pluridesciplanirité }
 % ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Quelque disciplines d'EIAH}
\begin{itemize}
\item Pédagogie .
    \pause
   \item Didactique .
\pause
\item Information et communication .
\pause
\item informatique 
\subitem IHM , IA ,Si
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. \subitem` is what i get with your code.

Comment: Indeed: where do you get `\subitem` from? You probably want a nested list ...

Comment: Add `\newcommand{\subitem}[1]{#1}`. If the error vanishes, your editor is not helpful for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B 
Now i get this error after deleting \subitem File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body

Comment: @medboy94: You use a `subsection` without having a `section` command before. That might cause problems.

Comment: @leandriis Did you find `\subitem` in the manual for `beamer`? I don't think so, because it's not defined by `beamer`. The command exists in the standard classes (such as `article`) for use in the index, not for general lists. Using it, even if it's defined, Is *always* an error.

Answer (score 4):

As various comments already stated: To create subitems in beamer, simply nest the `itemize` environments.

---

A few other remarks:

- instead of `\usepackage{beamerthemeWarsaw}` use `\usetheme{Warsaw}` (this is the more `beamer`ish way to load a theme)
- you don't need `\useoutertheme{shadow}`, this is already included in the `Warsaw` theme
- with `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` you don't need to manually put a `\pause` after each item.

---

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title[monExemple]{Un exemple sur le Beamer}
\subtitle{created with beamer 3.x}
\author[bela]{A.belahcene}
\institute{ IAP, Boumerdes}

\setbeamertemplate{itemise item }[ball]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=blue!50}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=white,bg=red}

\begin{document}   

\subsection{Pluridesciplanirité }

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Quelque disciplines d'EIAH}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Pédagogie .
        \item Didactique .
        \item Information et communication .
        \item informatique 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item IHM , IA ,Si
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```